# How to find out WCF service binding timeout value on the server

Tags: c#, wcf, soap, wcf-binding, endpoint

When making a web service request using SOAP you configure a binding like so

`<basicHttpBinding>
                <binding name="Secure_ApiService" sendTimeout="00:25:00">
                    <security mode="Transport">
                        <transport clientCredentialType="Basic" />
                    </security>
                </binding>
            </basicHttpBinding>`

As we are only consuming this service we don't know what the sendTimeout is configured to on the Server and it is my understanding that if a API call takes longer than either the sendTimeout on the Server or Client then an error occurs.

Is there a way to find out what the sendTimeout is configured to on the server side when you only know the endpoint of the service?

Answer (score 0):

The SendTimeOut is controlled on the client side as different clients could have different tolerances for how long they're willing to wait for a response.

Reference:   https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh924831(v=vs.110).aspx